# How MUI handle styles internally?

Tags: css, material-ui, styles

Our team is just starting to figure out how to create a design system on top of MUI and we are trying to figure out what's the best approach to working with styles.

Up to now, we understand that using CSS inline or CSS module the final styles will be on a separated chunk when we build the project.

Otherwise, when we use CSS in JS approach (Styled components or emotion) you don't have any CSS chunk when you build the project, because styles are on the JS chunks (making them a bit bigger) and then the final CSS is made in the browser side (theoretically hurting the performance).

I tried to check on MUI repository how you are handling styles in your project in order to follow the same approach and that way not mix different approaches, but I didn't understand your strategy. I saw some emotion dependencies, but I couldn't recognize some emotion regular sintaxis on the components. Can you explain to us a little bit how you are doing that?

And finally what way to handle styles do you think has less impact on performance when you create a design system on top of MUI? (following your same approach, using inline styles, styled components, emotion, or another one)

PD: this question is not regarding design tokens, just finding a way to handle the styles that don't affect the performance of the consumers of our design system.